# Customize footer in the Szeged Beamer theme

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using the Szeged theme in Beamer. I would like to modify the footer so that it contain, beside my short name and the institute in short, the frame number and the total number of frames on the right side of the footer. I have tried with the code below, but the footer only contains my name, the institute in short; an additional, undesired effect is that the colour of footer area is changed.

Is there a way of achieving this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, dvips, dvipsnames]{beamer}

%NOTES:
\setbeameroption{show notes}
%\setbeameroption{hide notes}


%PACKAGES
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%THEMES
\usetheme{Szeged}

\useinnertheme{default}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}


%TEMPLATE
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamertemplate{note page}[compress]

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]


%TOC
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\small, shape=\itshape}


%FOOTER:
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[width=0.333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1ex, center]{author in head/foot}%
       \usebeamerfont{authour in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[width=0.333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
       \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[width=0.333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
       \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
\vskip0pt%

}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My Frametitle}
A frame!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Szeged theme is basically nothing but

```
\useoutertheme[footline=institutetitle]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!50!bg}
```

A hybrid version of the `miniframes` outer theme's footline and your ansatz (which seems to come from the `infolines` outer theme) might look like

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.333333\paperwidth, ht=2.5ex, dp=1.125ex, center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

and might be just what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks alot! That did the trick! I had to frame it by \makeatletter and \makeatother and I a typo: 'authour' instead of 'author'.